# li > a padding is not filling parent li div

Tags: html, css

I want to add padding to my "a" element which will decide the height for the parent div. Although if I add it, the parent div remains unaffected. I cannot seem to figure it out at all.

It is a hamburger navbar menu. So when I click my icon, it should bring the navbar down and should be the same height that the "a" tag provides through padding.

```
<div id="side-menu" class="side-nav" v-bind:class="{'side-menu-open': isOpen}">
    <ul class="side">
        <li class="side"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="side"><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li class="side"><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
        <li class="side"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>


li.side {
    display:inline-block;
    margin-right: -4px;
}

li.side a {
    padding: 3em 2em;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: 0.3s ease;
}

li.side a:first-child {
    border-top: 1px solid #333;
}

li.side a:hover {
    background-color: #333;
    transition: 0.3s ease;
}

.side-nav {
    transition: 0.4s;
    background-color: #222;
    width: 100% !important;
    height:0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.open {
    transition: 1s;
}

.side-menu-open {
    height: 70px !important;
}

.open-slide {
    transition: 0.4s;
}

.open-slide:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Can you add a working snippet / demo? Thanks

Comment: https://codepen.io/donnieberry97/pen/oyjoeX

added just the base part of it, no functionality, as you can see, the padding doesnt make the li fill up

Comment: @DonnieBerry, did the answer below solve your problem? If so, you should click the big green checkbox next to the answer to "accept" it, so others will know this problem is solved

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the `height` from a fixed value to `auto` here.

```
.side-menu-open {
    height: auto;
}
```

By default, `a` is an inline element. Top and bottom padding will not apply. You can change the display type to `inline-block`.

```css
li.side {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: -4px;
}

li.side a {
  padding: 3em 2em;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.3s ease;
  /* added */
  display: inline-block;
}

li.side a:first-child {
  border-top: 1px solid #333;
}

li.side a:hover {
  background-color: #333;
  transition: 0.3s ease;
}

.side-nav {
  transition: 0.4s;
  background-color: #222;
  width: 100% !important;
  /*height: 0;*/
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.open {
  transition: 1s;
}

.side-menu-open {
  height: auto !important;
}

.open-slide {
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.open-slide:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
  <div id="side-menu" class="side-nav" v-bind:class="{'side-menu-open': isOpen}">
    <ul class="side">
      <li class="side"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li class="side"><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li class="side"><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
      <li class="side"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```